# Change a digit (unit, tenth or hundred) of a number?

Tags: arithmetic

I am trying to find most optimized formula for achieving following result.

For example,
There is a number 125. I need to change its tenth which is '2' to '7', resulting 175.

One formula that I derived:

```
= 125 + {(7 - (125 / 10 % 10)} * 10
= 125 + (7 - 2) * 10
= 125 + 50
= 175
```

But, what if I have to change unit or hundred or x digit of a number?

Comment: Optimized how? For programming? For x86/x86_64 processor arithmetic? For Java implementation? For GCC 4.8? For JavaScript?

Comment: Optimized for programming or even better idea or formula!

Comment: If it's for "general" programming, then your idea is as optimized as they get because it's in $O(1)$, and you can't get better than that. In generally, this seems more like a question about programming than it is about mathematics, and I think that it might fit better on StackOverflow.com than this site.

Comment: If you want to change the k-th digit from the right, just replace the $10$'s with $10^{k-1}$ (except for the % 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace digit **D** with digit **Z** in number x = ...Def (digit representing **hundreds**), one can use code

```
... = x - x%1000 + x%100 + Z*100;
```

To replace digit **D** with digit **Z** in number x = ...Defg (digit representing **thousands**), one can use code

```
    ... = x - x%10000 + x%1000 + Z*1000;
```

And so on.

---

(C/C++/Java code style).

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the $k$th digit (from the right) of the positive number $x$ is a $d$ and you want to change it to $d'$, just add $(d'-d)\cdot 10^{k-1}$ to $x$. If you don't know $d$ beforehand, you can find it as $d=\left\lfloor \frac x{10^{k-1}}\right\rfloor\bmod 10$. If you also have to deal with negative $x$, it is easiest to deal with $|x|$ and re-multiply with the sign of $x$ in the end.

Comment: No amount of addition will change the tenth digit in $199$ without changing the hundredth as well.